# "The RPC server is unavailable" Error on Azure Could Server 2019

Tags: azure, abbyy

This is regarding Abbyy Setup issue that we are facing on a Azure Cloud Machine which is a Windows Server 2019 VM.

We followed the Admin Guide for Reader 12, the "Manual Runtime Installation Steps" were followed for the setup. The Bin64, Data and Inc folders are copied into a directory which will be later used while registering FREngine.dll on the OS. *We have not done the Abbyy SDK installation.*

We have VM setup locally which is a Windows Server 2019 VM image. On this setup we are able to Register the FREngine.dll successfully using regsvr32 command. Also we don’t see any issue and is working, w.r.t reading OCR/Barcode values successfully through Abbyy FineReader.

**ISSUE**

The issue is on the Azure Cloud System [VM Windows Server 2019], where we are able to Register the FREngine.dll successfully using regsvr32 command. However even with the successful Registration of FREngine.dll, when we try to initialize the FREngine, we are getting an exception "Invalid Engine instance" during the call to `InitializeEngine( )` with all the Required parameters set.

```
// Create the abbyy engine instance in outproc process, 
// as its recommended by Abbyy for 64-bit process

outProcLoader = new OutprocLoader();
if (outProcLoader != null)
     engine = outProcLoader.InitializeEngine(AbbyyEngineUtils._strProjectId,
                                             engLicensePath, 
                                             AbbyyEngineUtils._strEngPwd, 
                                             "", "", true);
```

Here we have a license file which is also copied into the location where FREngine.dll is present.

Due to this initial Step failure Abbyy Logs could not be generated from the codebase. However we see a log file that gets generated from Abbyy in the path “C:\ProgramData\ABBYY\SDK\12\FineReader Engine\” at this point of failure which states as follows:

> 10552 :ABBYY Licensing Service is unavailable: The RPC server is
> unavailable.

We also we additionally tried running the Abbyy SDK’s Sample applications on this machine. This also fails with the above error during Abbyy Engine Initialization.

How can this be resolved?

**More Info on Licensing Service:**

We additionally tried installing the LicensingService and the LicensingSettings.XML had :

ProtocolType="LocalInterprocessCommunication" />

Here Ours is a Standalone Abbyy Installation and hence the Protocol Type used is LocalInterprocessCommunication which is for the local Licensing Service. It is not necessary to specify this protocol type for Standalone installation, as Standalone licenses are always used with the LocalInterprocessCommunication protocol type.

This was an additional Step tried by us. However the actual issue was with the Abbyy Licensing on Azure.

Comment: This issue was due to the Limitation on the Abbyy License on Azure. This issue stands Closed. Thanks.

Comment: How did you get the limitation lifted?

Comment: @Bek Azure VM was not included in our license. Hence we no longer use Azure for our development.

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to start the abbyy licensing service in the Azure VM ?

- (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) Run command --> `services.msc`
- In the **Services Dialog**, find the Abby...Licensing service.
- Right Click -> Properties
- You can click on the start and click `ok`.

Retry your above steps.  Also, you could have startup type as Automatic if this works in the services in dialog.

Comment: We have tried this option and now the Error Message is "2816 :There are no licenses on <machine name>". We do have a valid Abbyy License which works correctly on a Standalone VM but fails on the Azure Cloud VM.

Comment: I would begin checking with the LicensingSettings.xml file. https://support.abbyy.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012283259-How-to-configure-FineReader-Engine-licensing-settings-to-use-a-Network-License

Comment: Ours is a Standalone Installation and the LicenseSettings.XML seems to be correct which is : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><LicensingSettings xmlns="http://www.abbyy.com/Protection/LicensingSettings"> ProtocolType="LocalInterprocessCommunication" /></LocalLicenseServer></LicensingSettings>

Comment: @Priya could you update your post with that xml and the intention of what you hope to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

As any other OCR solution some have licensing constraint to run on Azure and AWS , make sure your license is compatible.
as posted here
https://support.abbyy.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016441600-Can-I-run-FineReader-Engine-in-Virtual-Machine-or-Container-

also I would check the OS compatible version.

ABBYY SDK 12 Licensing Service has been tested in the following virtual environments:
Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2
Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows 7 SP1